# How can i change IKImageBrowserView’s doubleclick behaviour?

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, double-click, ikimagebrowserview, nsresponder

I use a `IKImageBrowserView` in a Mac 10.9-only application.

When I doubleclick an item in the `IKImageBrowserView` the item is opened in Preview.

I want to change this behaviour and open a window of my own application with details about the doubleclicked item instead.

How can i simply disable `IKImageBrowserView`’s doubleclick behaviour?
What is the best way to add my own doubleclick behaviour?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[As per apple docs](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/graphicsimaging/Reference/IKImageBrowserDelegate_Protocol/IKImageBrowserDelegate_Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/NSObject/imageBrowser%3acellWasDoubleClickedAtIndex%3a), you need to set up a delegate for `IKImageBrowserView` and you can add your custom implementation in `cellWasDoubleClicked` method.

```
- (void) imageBrowser:(IKImageBrowserView *) aBrowser cellWasDoubleClickedAtIndex:(NSUInteger) index {
    // This method signals that the user double-clicked an item in the image browser view. 
    // You can implement this method if you want to perform custom tasks at that time.
}
```